# How do modern CPU manufacturers determine the suitable base clock and the associated power?

Tags: power, cpu

Modern CPUs have very smart boosting strategies. When idle, they automatically underclock to conserve energy. When busy, they automatically boost or overclock. The adjustments are so dynamic today that many CPUs hardly ever runs exactly at the base clock.

This fact leads to the question--if the CPU does not adhere to the base clock, what does the "base clock" shown on the specifications (and displayed by the Windows task manager) mean?

One guess is that it is the supposed "normal" working clock, so that the CPU would consume a "reasonable" amount of power while maintaining "fair" performance.

This, however, doesn't address the essence of the question. Why hasn't the manufacturer simply set the base clock at a slightly different point on the power-performance curve with a slightly lower or higher TDP, but the point ultimately marketed? If it stands for some kind of "sweet spot," why are players often able to find different sweet points? Is there some internal criterion for the decision?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is the correct forum to post this question. It is welcome if you suggest moving this question to more suitable site of StackExchange.

Comment: There is such a thing as engineering judgement. It very much comes down to what you decide is "reasonable" and "fair" and that is going to vary from user to user and engineer to engineer. We all value different things.

Answer (score 6):

> This fact leads to the question--if the CPU does not adhere to the base clock, what does the "base clock" shown on the specifications (and displayed by the Windows task manager) mean?

Different manufacturers have different definitions, so there is no one single answer.  But usually the base clock is intended to be some minimum level of performance that should be obtainable within some proscribed thermal/power envelope.  For more specific answer, look up the documentation for your CPU.

> Why hasn't the manufacturer simply set the base clock at a slightly different point on the power-performance curve with a slightly lower or higher TDP, but the point ultimately marketed?

Typically manufacturers pick one or more points that have enough market demand to justify an SKU.  Obviously if there is no demand they don't offer it.  Intel for example offers most of their CPUs in a low base clock, low power limit configuration ('T' CPUs), a medium/medium configuration, and a high/high configuration ('K').

> If it stands for some kind of "sweet spot," why are players often able to find different sweet points? Is there some internal criterion for the decision?

Because different people have different preferences.  This is also why most many manufacturers let you customize things like power limits.  Different applications will have different needs.

Answer (score 2):

CPU makers will tend to use their maximum throughput and therefore max clock rate for benchmarking comparisons.

The figures you’re hinting at are more like those used for specialized tasks like AI inferencing for example. These will be rated in J/inference.

It is possible to get characterized workload vs. power data from systems vendors using known benchmarks as a way to gauge the relative efficiency of a compute resource.